# Closing Duplicate Questions on StackOverflow?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Twice today (11/17/14), I saw duplicate questions asked within 6 to 12 hours of each other (by separate users who copied and pasted almost identical text).  I went to flag them as duplicate, but you can only flag as duplicate if there is an accepted or up-voted answer on the original.  I understand this policy, but there should be an option to flag a duplicate if it is within a certain time frame.  Is there a rule on when you can re-post or how long you must wait before re-posting an unanswered question?

Edit:  The feature request would be to have two options in "Flag as Duplicate".  The first being "Flag as Duplicate - Answered" and "Flag as Duplicate - Time" then set a range of time when re-posting an unanswered question was not allowed.

Comment: Just flag as "other" or bring it up on chat.

Comment: That is what I did.  But I think it should be included in the "flag as duplicate" option because it allows you to link back to the duplicate post in the flag.

Comment: That's a fishy smell.  Fishy smells are best flagged "other" and give the mods all the info you have on the odor.